# Tarjan Algorithm for SCC worst case analysis

Tags: algorithm, graph, tarjans-algorithm

I was reading Donal B .Johnson's paper for finding all elementary circuits in a directed graph, http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150GA/homeworks/hw1/Johnson%2075.PDF

In this paper he mentioned that worst case for Tarjan Algorithm is O(V*E (c+1))
While everywhere else it is shown as O(V+E), Johnson paper has taken couple of example to prove that point , Like Fig 1 and Fig 2 on the paper.

Fig 2 example which is fairly similar , after finding first cycle 1...k in O(k) time , now as per my understanding all the other vertcies will simply return as their index is already defined and it should take another k time for k vertices, so to sump up it should 2k times instead of k**2 , am I missing some point here ?

Please suggest with some example , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tarjan's algorithm" is in this case not the algorithm for strongly connected components. It is his algorithm for enumerating elementary circuits. However, in [the original paper](http://ecommons.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/5941/1/72-145.pdf), this method is noted as having a tight worst case O((V + E) * (C + 1)) time. It is interesting to note that the argument Tarjan uses to prove this bound (O(V + E) time between finding two circuits) is suddenly changed in Johnson's paper (O(V * E) time between finding two circuits). I'm not familiar with either of these algorithms, so I can't say which one is correct. A quick search seems to regard Johnson's algorithm as being asymptotically faster (even though both methods claim the same time complexity), but nowhere could I find a source that disproves the time complexity in Tarjan's paper.

Comment: SIAM  paper introduction does says that Tarjan Algorithm for Elementary Circuit does take O(e.v(c+1)) http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0202017

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking for a faster method: Somebody checked Tarjan against Johnson and another method and found another method that claims to be faster, but at least more flexible:
[link to writeup](https://blog.mister-muffin.de/2012/07/04/enumerating-elementary-circuits-of-a-directed_graph/)
and [link to paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221440635_Enumerating_Circuits_and_Loops_in_Graphs_with_Self-Arcs_and_Multiple-Arcs) (called "Enumerating Circuits and Loops in Graphs with Self-Arcs and Multiple-Arcs." by K.A. Hawick and H.A. James)

All method need an implementation in the same language proper benchmarking to have reliable results.